# Array inside a for loop, inside a forloop - throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, coin-flipping

I want to flip 5 coins as a group - 1024 times and count how many tails i get. However i am getting  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 error.

Is this because j in the second loop is not reset when the first loop runs its first time? If so, how would i go about this then?

```
public class Q2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int totalTails, totalHeads;
        int coin[];

        coin = new int[4];

        totalHeads = 0;
        totalTails = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
            for (int j=0; i<5; j++){
            coin[j] = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * (2 - 1 + 1));
                if (coin[j] == 1) {
                    totalHeads++;
                }
                    else {
                        totalTails++;
                    }
                }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of  tails were obtained = " + totalTails);
        System.out.println("Number of heads were obtained = " + totalHeads);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j=0; i<5; j++){
```

It should be j<5

```
coin = new int[4];
```

It should be int[5]

Comment: Thanks buddy - didnt see that i had a i instead of a j. Silly mistake. But why should int[4] be int[5]? I thought arrays run from 0. So if i needed 5 objects, shouldnt it be int[4] as in 0,1,2,3,4?

Comment: Yes, array does run from 0 but when you announce an array, the number inside [ ] is the maximum number of elements of that array. E.g. int[5] equals an array of 5 integer numbers at maximum.
Consequently, you have to loop your array from 0 to length-1. Therefore for(j=0;j<array.length;j++)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
for (int j=0; i<5; j++){
```

To this line:

```
for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
```

You are going out of bounds on `coin`

It would be even better if you use `length` property. Like th

```
for (int j=0; j<coin.length; j++){
```

Comment: Thank you Laerte. coin.length makes absolute sense.

Answer (score 0):

please change `for (int j=0; i<5; j++)` to `for (int j=0; j<5; j++)` and your code should work fine.

Comment: In your answer is no changes. Both statements are equals.